# alternate method to do mail merge to create letters for mIllions of employees country wide

Tags: oracle, email, merge, vbscript

Hi here I am reposting my query..

I have more than million records of employee in oracle table having emp id , name,designation ,office Id and address.

I need to generate letter for each employee using word template(include company logo image), and save it as pdf..

Single pdf for each office, containing letters pertaining to employees of that office...

I have written a batch file to extract data from oracle using pls all and save it in CSV.

Then I call open word document with open_document macro to merge CSV data with word template to generate letters and then save result as pdf

Batch file is
——————————————————

```
For /f "delims=" %%x in (office I’d.txt) do (

 sqlplus userid/pass@emp @createcsv.sql %%x  

 move /Y %%x.lst %%x.CSV

echo %%x > datasourcename.txt

 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe" /x /q newtemp.dotm
```

———————-—————————————

My dotm  file contains macro named open_document to perform mail merge and close document after saving pdf file.

This works fine at home PC.. but in office coz macros are disabled,open_document is not working.

To over come that. I write macro code to vbscript file. And called it from batch file.
vbscript :::---

---

```
Dim strPath
Dim strDataSource
Dim strTemplate
Dim doc
Dim wrdApp

Set args = Wscript.Arguments
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wrdApp.Options.Pagination = False ' suppress pagination

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strPath=.CurrentDirectory

 End With

  strDataSource = args.Item(0) 

   strTemplate = "Annexure11.dot"

'Start Word using mailmerge template
wrdApp.Documents.Open (strPath & "\" & strTemplate)


Set oMergeDoc = wrdApp.ActiveDocument

Set oMerge = oMergeDoc.MailMerge

oMerge.MainDocumentType = 0 
msgBox "Before Open Datasource"
oMerge.OpenDataSource strPath & "\" & strDataSource &".csv" 
msgBox "After Open Datasource"
oMerge.Destination = 0 ' 0 = wdSendToNewDocument

omerge.SuppressBlankLines=True

omerge.DataSource.FirstRecord=1

omerge.DataSource.LastRecord=-16
 
If omerge.State=2 then oMerge.Execute pause= false 

'Do not display the mail merge document
wrdApp.Visible = False

'Save mail merge document as doc and pdf
  wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strPath & "\"& arg(0) &".pdf" , 17
  wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strPath  &".doc" 

  omergedoc.Close False
  wrdApp.Quit 
  Set wrdApp = Nothing
  GetObject(, "Word.Application").Quit False
```

---

when I run the above code, I get msgbox with msg "Before Open Datasource" but never gets msg "After Open Datasource"

*Please suggest some alternate method to get desired output.

Comment: Please expand on "not working".

Comment: Don't you think you should look into a professional way to generate **millions** of documents? This is like trying to bake a million breads in your home kitchen; it's never going to scale.